# How to convert xml string to xlsx string?

Tags: javascript, c#, xml, excel

I used ParamQuery Grid Pro javascript library for create grid then i used export excel function to export grid data in to excel file now it default create xml extension file but i need xlsx file if any suggestion to convert this xml string to xlsx string and download ?

Thanks

Comment: xlsx is the Excel file extension. What do you mean by "xlsx string"?

Comment: That XML can be opened in Excel and saved as xlsx.